# Symfony2: limiting sending of emails per ip

Tags: php, email, symfony, limit

I have a `symfony2` project, where a contact form sends emails. I want to make a limit that one ip address can send only two emails per hour. Is there a bundle for this?

Comment: may be you shoud create a data table save ips, and check it before mail send

Comment: In symfony standard edition you can not control sends email per ip. And you can create custom `worker` for AMQP or CRON for control this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Beanstalkd is a simple, fast work queue. This is IMHO best solution for you. 
And it has Bundle for Symfony:  https://github.com/armetiz/LeezyPheanstalkBundle